# Two Textblocks in same row

Tags: winrt-xaml

In stackpanel, I want two textblocks in same row.
[image]

in the image, I want the date and time at the same row.
what should I do?

Following is source code:

```
 <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="2015/03/01"  Margin="15,0,15,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="1:42:31" Margin="15,0,15,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default Orientation of StackPanel is Vertical, hence the three TextBlocks appear one below the other. You should add another StackPanel with its Orientation set to Horizontal and put the bottom two TextBlocks inside it.

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Title"  Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="2015/03/01"  Margin="15,0,15,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>            
            <TextBlock Text="1:42:31" Margin="15,0,15,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Updated:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Title"  Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="2015/03/01" Grid.Column="0" Margin="15,0,15,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="1:42:31" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's very helpful. But I have another problem now. I want the time(1:42:31) to right side in stackpanel. I set it property HorizontalAlignment="Right", but it doesn't work.  change Margin value can complete, but I think that isn't smart. what should I do? thx. Following imgur URL is what I mean. http://imgur.com/gsIxi7D

Comment: in that case, you should use a Grid instead of StackPanel. I've modified the xaml above.